# Gurobi add constraint which two variables cant be zero at the same time

Tags: gurobi

I'm currently using Gurobi in python and trying to add a constraint that the variable will not equal to 0 at the same time, for example, `a != 0 or b != 0`. But I can't find a proper function to add this constraint.
Anyone have idea about this?

Comment: If a and b are non-negative and contiguous, you can impose the constraint `a+b >= ε` where ε is a sufficiently small positive number. If a and b are non-negative integers, you can choose ε = 1.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an extension such that a and b can also be negative numbers?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because optimization modeling belongs in or.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll look over there and close this post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.